# There's no input tag where there should be one

Tags: selenium

I'm making a Facebook marketplace bot. And i'm only missing the picture uploading part.

Here are all the tags where the input tag should be. I tried sending the keys method into the span tag but obviously the element is not reachable by keyboard so it FAILED!

[image: HTML]

I also tried sending the keys to every div i could, but i had no success.

What else can i do in this case?
I'm a linux user if that matters.

Comment: Why is there a python tag here? This looks like a HTML question.

Comment: I coding it in python. I just removed the tag. Thanks for comment it out.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: uploading usually use some `<input type="file">` and keys/filenam has to be send to this element. Other elements may only hide this `<input>` to create better design but may not accept keys.